# Any risks of changing master roles of Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I am currently migrating an Active Directory to another server, from a Windows Server 2012 to a 2016 one. I installed AD in 2016 and joined the domain with no problems. Now I am considering changing the master roles to the new server. Are there any risks in doing this procedure?

Comment: To proceed with the transfer of FSMO roles, we consider that DCs that already have a role are active in our infrastructure. Otherwise, if a DC holding a FSMO role is no longer online and operational, then we use the seize method instead of simple transfer.
Before you move a role, you need to know where the FSMO roles are in the Domain Controllers. For more details, please refer to this article:[Transfer FSMO roles to another Domain Controller](https://www.dtonias.com/transfer-fsmo-roles-domain-controller/)

Answer (score 1):

If your AD replication is working correctly, there is no risk at all; use `dcdiag` and `repadmin` to check everything is working correctly before moving a FSMO role, and make sure all DCs are online so that they can properly acknowledge the change.

Also, make sure the server that will hold the PDC Emulator role has correct time settings, because it will become the authoritative time source for the domain.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to manually reconfigure the Windows Time service on the new PDCe and the old PDCe. You can run the commands below in an elevated command prompt on the respective servers to make this change.

**New PDCe**

net stop w32time

w32tm /unregister

w32tm /register

net start w32time

w32tm.exe /config /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:YES /update

net stop w32time

net start w32time

**Old PDCe**

net stop w32time

w32tm /unregister

w32tm /register

net start w32time

w32tm /config /syncfromflags:DOMHIER /update

net stop w32time

net start w32time